# Instance level access on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to give full access on AWS EC2 instance for a single instance, and deny any action on other instances.

Can it be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: SSH access, or AWS Console access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the edited question, the answer is yes.

You restrict access to the AWS console using [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/). If gives you detailed control on what individual users or groups can do. For example you can say "John can restart all instances tagged production but only between the hours of 8pm and 5pm". You can control access to individual resources or groups of resources, services, functions within services, etc.

You can also federate users with existing directories, and give temporary credentials. I'm not going to give more detail on that because it's an advanced topic and your question is fairly simplistic.

If you want to control ssh access to an EC2 instance, create users on that instance using standard Unix mechanisms, ideally requiring certificate authentication. Don't give out the certificate for the ec2-user that AWS creates for you, create new users and new certificates. A tutorial [like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) will walk you through it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that any user on the server will also have access to any IAM instance roles that the machine is provisioned with, unless steps are taken to specifically deny that network traffic.

Comment: ok, how can I achieve giving full access for instances with a certain tag only, and prevent it for the rest.

Comment: Example here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-ec2-tag-permissions  . Note that AWS documentation is extensive, Google is a very effective way to work most things AWS out.